# Display 1 graph per category in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I'm looking for a programmatic way to generate individual plots within the same view, based on one category.

[Example] imagine the following DF:

```
country       agg_meat_consumption_tons       month
  US                  300                      JAN
  BR                  100                      JAN
  IN                  10                       JAN
  RU                  200                      JAN
  US                  400                      FEB
  BR                  300                      FEB
  IN                  5                        FEB
  RU                  240                      FEB
  US                  150                      MAR
  BR                  90                       MAR
  IN                  10                       MAR
  RU                  400                      MAR
```

If I want to generate a plot that illustrates consumption across months per country I know that I can write something like:

```
df_pv = df.pivot_table(
    values='agg_meat_consumption_tons',
    index='month',
    columns='country')
```

However, I want to produce separate graphs for each country and print all the results in the same view. Essentially, something programmatic that allows me to avoid writing something like this for each country:

```
df_us = df[df['country']=='US']
df_us_pv = df_us.pivot_table(
    values='agg_meat_consumption_tons',
    index='month',
    columns='country')
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated my answer to your comments below--I'm not great with matplotlib but this will get you 90% of the way there.  Anyone else please feel free to add/edit.

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# %matplotlib inline

df
Out[12]: 
   country  consump  veg_amt month
0       US      300       94   JAN
1       BR      100       38   JAN
2       IN       10       40   JAN
3       RU      200       97   JAN
4       US      400       73   FEB
..     ...      ...      ...   ...
7       RU      240       20   FEB
8       US      150       72   MAR
9       BR       90       39   MAR
10      IN       10       46   MAR
11      RU      400       79   MAR

# Map month text values to numeric for sorting, remap later
months = ({(datetime.datetime(2000,i,1).strftime("%b")).upper(): 
           i for i in range(1, 13)})
inv_month  = {v: k for k, v in months.items()}

ptable = df.pivot_table(
    values=['consump', 'veg_amt'],
    index=df.month.map(months),
    columns='country')

ptable = ptable.swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
ptable.index = Series(ptable.index).map(inv_month)

ptable
Out[86]: 
country      BR              IN              RU              US        
        consump veg_amt consump veg_amt consump veg_amt consump veg_amt
month                                                                  
JAN         100      38      10      40     200      97     300      94
FEB         300      54       5      74     240      20     400      73
MAR          90      39      10      46     400      79     150      72

cols = ptable.columns.get_level_values(0).unique()
num_countries = len(df.country.unique())

fig, axes = plt.subplots(num_countries, sharex=True)
for col, num in zip(cols, range(num_countries)):
    ptable.xs(col, axis=1).plot(ax=axes[num])
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is great!

Comment: Thanks, @Bard Solomon. In addition to this view, I have a more complex structure with 2 continuous variables: meat_amt & veg_amt per month by country. How can I manipulate correctly to account for the additional variable?

Comment: You're saying you want both of those variables included in a single graph for each country?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to show 2 independent continuous variables over a given timeperiod for each category (country).

Answer (score 1):

you could try using a loop? Are you looking for an individual table for each country? if so:

```
# Turning that column to a list
country = df['country'].tolist()

for country in country:
    df_us = df[df['country']==str(country)]
    df_us_pv = df_us.pivot_table(
    values='agg_meat_consumption_tons',
    index='month',
    columns='country')

    # just printing for output
    print(df_us_pv)
```